# not change font font in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I seem to be right, however the font on my VM is still the same even after many reruns, My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import AppStatusBar from '../components/AppStatusBar';
import Colors from '../theme/Colors';

const SplashScreen = () => {
 return (
   <View>
     <AppStatusBar />
     <Text style={styles.textStyle}>abc</Text>
   </View>
 );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 textStyle: {
   fontSize: 35,
   fontWeight: '700',
   color: Colors.while,
   fontFamily: 'Poppins Bold',
 },
});

export default SplashScreen;
```

thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add the fonts to the assets of the app before you can use them. I recommend this guide to do so : https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app